# Number of days in between given two dates treating number of days in month as fixed 30 days

Tags: excel, date

I need to calculate difference between two dates with a fixed 30 days a month logic. The example is shown below

1. Start date = 10/4/2018
2. End date = 28/10/2018
3. Expected number of days between = 199 
   (Excel calculation of difference of days => 28/10/2018 - 10/4/2018 = 201 which is not what I need)
   The basis for calculation of difference between two dates is, it should consider number of days in a month as 30 days irrespective of the month. So all months in between the start & end dates with 31 days should be treated as 30 days. If there is Feb in between, it should also be taken as 30 days month.

Procedure to calculate number of days in between two given dates:

1. Fraction of days in the starting month = 30/4/2018 - 10/4/2018 = 21 days
2. Months in between 1/5/2018 to 30/9/2018 = 5 months = 5 x 30 = 150 days
3. Fraction of days in the last month = 28/10/2018 - 1/10/2018 = 28 days

Total days = 21 + 150 + 28 = 199 days.

If A1 is start date cell, B1 = End date cell, please suggest how to do it in excel.

Comment: What if the start or end dates fall on the 31st?  ie., how many days is `Jan 31 to March 31` , and how does that compare to `Jan 30 to April 1` or `Jan 29 to April 2`?

Comment: If the start date is 31st Jan, it should consider as 1 day for January month. The days in between Jan 31 and Mar 31 are => 1 day for Jan, 30 days for Feb, 30 days for Mar => 1 + 30 + 30 = 61 days

Comment: Number of days between 30/4/2018 and 10/4/2018 are 21 days. The days are inclusive. So + 1 is to be added to the difference. Thank you for quick response.

Comment: is there any chance you're excluding other days from the calculation afterwards, like weekends?  I've never seen any forms of accounting that exclude 8 days a year.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))<>31))` and I will let you figure out Feb's, Jan 31 and leap year adjustments.

Comment: @Suma - "inclusive" so Jan 1 to Jan 2 is 2 days, right?

Comment: @Suma - okay I pretty much give up on this.  But just to confirm, `Feb 28 to Mar 1` is **always** `4 days` (**regardless** of whether it's a leap year), correct?

Comment: no deductions for weekends. This is simplified way of calculating the fee. All months to be treated as 30 days a month. Fraction of days treated as number of days. These are hiring charges. There are charges for month and charges for days. So no exclusions for weekends.

Comment: yes, if we take the vehicle on Jan 1st and returned on Jan 2nd, it is considered as 2 days rental.

Comment: From Feb 28th to Mar 1 is counted with days logic as there are no full months in between. So it is 2 fractions of months which are to be calculated in days. In this case, Feb month balance is counted in days = 1 day (If it is leap year = 2 days). Mar month fraction is 1 day. So if it is a non leap year, the hiring days are = 2

Comment: For all full months between the dates, they are considered as 30 days a month logic. Month rate is applied for full months at standard. For all fraction of months, considered as number of days. Days rate is applied to calculate number of days rental and added to full months rate

Answer (score 1):

I've broken the formula into the three components as in your example:
[image: screen shot]

The formulas in D2:G2 are:

```
D2: =IF(AND(YEAR(A2)=YEAR(B2),MONTH(A2)=MONTH(B2)),MIN(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30),B2),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30))-MIN(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30),A2)+1
E2: =MAX(((YEAR(B2)-YEAR(A2))*12+MONTH(B2)-MONTH(A2)-1)*30,0)
F2: =MIN(IF(AND(YEAR(B2)=YEAR(A2),MONTH(B2)=MONTH(A2)),0,B2-DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),1)+1),30)
G2: =SUM(D2:F2)
```

or, all in one:

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(A2)=YEAR(B2),MONTH(A2)=MONTH(B2)),MIN(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30),B2),DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30))-MIN(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),30),A2)+1+MAX(((YEAR(B2)-YEAR(A2))*12+MONTH(B2)-MONTH(A2)-1)*30,0)+MIN(IF(AND(YEAR(B2)=YEAR(A2),MONTH(B2)=MONTH(A2)),0,B2-DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),1)+1),30)
```

I like the elegance of @Jeeped 's code, but this might be easier to follow.

Comment: @ashleedawg - this formula correctly returns 2 for your Jan 31 to Feb 1 example.

Comment: Jan 31 to Mar 31 should be 61, and Feb 28 to Mar 1 should be 4.

Comment: Fixed formula (again) to account for Feb 28-Mar1 being 4 days (Feb 28 to Feb 30 = 3, plus Mar 1 = 3+1)

Comment: @RobGale, yes, if Feb is either start or end of the month, then it should consider actual days in the month of Feb and calculate days rate for the month. If Feb falls in between the start and end months as a full month, then monthly rate is applied to Feb irrespective of number of days in the month

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))<>31))+
(DAY(A2)=31)+
 SIGN(SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))=2)*(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))=28)))*2
```

Comment: This returns `4` for `Jan 31 to Feb 1`.  (I'm don't know why I'm still spending time on this))

Comment: extremely helpful ashleedawg. Thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: out of the suggestions, I tested and =SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A2&":"&B2)))<>31)) formula suits for the scenario perfectly by treating Feb month in parts and in months as a whole. Thank you very much. Great solutions.

Comment: Only one case, the Sumproduct formula doesn't work. 31/1/2018 to 31/3/2018 - The calculation is => Days for start month (Jan = 1 day) +  Full months for in-between months (No of full months = 2, Feb full month = 1 month = considered as 30 days + Mar full month = 30days)  = 61 days. Sumproduct formula gives 58 days.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your examples are a little "wonky", like how the 31st counts sometimes (like if it's the start/end date) but not others.

Anyway, this function ain't pretty but it does the trick:

```
Function No31st(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Long
    Dim d As Date
    For d = startDate To endDate 'iterate each day in range
        If Day(d) <= 30 Then 'count days up to the 30th
            No31st = No31st + 1
            'if it's Feb 28, add 2 more days
            If (Month(d) = 2 And Day(d) = 28) Then
                No31st = No31st + 2 ' + Feb 29 + Feb 30
                If Day(d + 1) <> 1 Then d = d + 1 'leap year
            End If
        End If
    Next d
    'since the 31st counts if it's the last day:
    If Day(startDate) = 31 Or Day(endDate) = 31 Then No31st = No31st + 1
End Function
```

### Sample Output:

```
StartDate   endDate    result
10/4/2018   28/10/2018  199
31/1/2018   31/3/2018    61
28/2/2018   1/3/2018      4
28/2/2000   1/3/2000      4
31/1/2018   1/2/2018      2
```

Comment: brilliant solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The `DAYS360` formula is based on the 12 30-day month logic.

Answer (score 0):

Simple & Easy Ways:

**(1)**

```
=YEARFRAC(start_date,end_date,4)*360
```

**(2)**

```
=DAYS360(start_date,end_date)
```